# Como saber o tamanho do JFrame no construtor do mesmo?

Tags: java, swing

Preciso de ajustar o tamanho da imagem ao espaço disponibilizado pelo `jframe`.

Erro:

> ```
> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Width (0) and height (0) must be non-zero
>     at java.awt.image.ReplicateScaleFilter.<init>(ReplicateScaleFilter.java:102)
>     at java.awt.image.AreaAveragingScaleFilter.<init>(AreaAveragingScaleFilter.java:77)
>     at java.awt.Image.getScaledInstance(Image.java:172)
> ```

Código que estou a usar para redimensionar a imagem (no construtor, tanto o  `this.getSize().width` como o `this.getSize().height` está a 0):

```
            try {
                bgImg = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("Images/dummy-image.jpg"));


                double scaleFactor = Math.min(1d, getScaleFactorToFit(new Dimension(bgImg.getWidth(), bgImg.getHeight()), new Dimension(this.getSize().width,this.getSize().height)));

                int scaleWidth = (int) Math.round(bgImg.getWidth() * scaleFactor);
                int scaleHeight = (int) Math.round(bgImg.getHeight() * scaleFactor);

                Image scaled = bgImg.getScaledInstance(scaleWidth, scaleHeight, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);

                labelAux.setSize(this.getSize().width, this.getSize().height);
                labelAux.setIcon(new ImageIcon(scaled));
                slideContainer.setPref_H(this.getSize().height);
                slideContainer.setPref_W(this.getSize().width);
                slideContainer.insertComponentEffect(labelAux, "");
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(ThePanelForImagesFitMaxImg.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
```

Como estou a usar esta biblioteca para criar efeitos não posso definir medidas estáticas...

[Biblioteca](https://github.com/AurelienRibon/sliding-layout)

Exemplo do uso da biblioteca:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Exemplo da app:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não tem como, a janela ainda nem foi construida, como saber seu tamanho?

Comment: Talvez inserindo um [mcve] seja possivel analisar melhor o problema. Infelizmente nem todos podem ver as imagens por razoes de bloqueio.

Comment: @Articuno o código é demasiado extenso para o colocar todo, se colocar o construtor ajuda? eu também já tinha pensado nisso, de se a janela ainda não está construida não pode ter um tamanho atribuído... Contudo não existe uma forma de lançar um evento quando a janela estiver pronta?

Comment: A sugestão é você elaborar um [mcve] somente com o caso da imagem, não a classe inteira, somente o necessário para reproduzir o problema. Sem executar fica dificil sugerir algo que possa solucionar e não te gerar outro problema diferente.

Comment: Ou tente essa solução(que acho bem ruim, apesar de válida): https://stackoverflow.com/a/1065136/5524514

Answer (score 1):

Somente será possível descobrir o tamanho de uma janela após este ser definido, ora seja através dos métodos [`setSize(Dimension d)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setSize-java.awt.Dimension-) ou [`setSize(int width, int height)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setSize-int-int-) que definem um tamanho fixo, ora por meio dos métodos de tamanho relativo, que é o caso do [`setPreferredSize(Dimension preferredSize)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setPreferredSize-java.awt.Dimension-), [`setMaximumSize(Dimension maximumSize)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setMaximumSize-java.awt.Dimension-) ou [`setMinimumSize(Dimension minimumSize)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setMinimumSize-java.awt.Dimension-).

Cada um destes métodos possui um `getter` específico para que você consiga recuperar o valor definido a eles, mas no caso do métodos de tamanho relativo como `setPreferredSize()`, quando nenhum valor for definido, o `get` só retornará algum valor que seja condizente com o tamanho da janela após o método `pack()`ser invocado, pois este é quem irá validar a janela e forçar o gerenciador de layout a adequar da melhor forma possível os componentes dentro dela.

No caso do `setSize`, se você definir um tamanho por ele antes da invocação do `pack()`, estes os valores serão substituídos por um novo valor de tamanho que será definido pelo gerenciador de layouts após a construção da tela.